# Which API version for Android 2.3.6?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I need to make an app for an android 2.3.6. Which SDK Should I use? SDK Manager only shows 2.3.3 API 10 as the highest one.

Answer (score 21):

[The Android API level list](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) says that the highest API level you can use for 2.3.6 is API level 10. The next higher level 11 requires at least Android 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

use 2.3.6 API 10 which full fills your requirement

If you use 2.2 or  2.1 it also help you to make it compatible for lower versions