# Why android reference does not list "Android 2.3.5–2.3.7" as API 10?

Tags: android

In the android documentation there is nothing about Android 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Wikipedia however [lists those as API 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_2.3.3.E2.80.932.3.7_Gingerbread_.28API_level_10.29) and other [answers say it's API 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042141/which-api-version-for-android-2-3-6). Which is the logical thing since API 11 starts with Android 3.0 and there is no such thing like API 10,5...

So did they simply forget to mention it in the android reference? Or is that some kind of "unofficial Android" ?

Comment: I'd bet on "just forgotten", but that's pure speculation. If you really want to know you'd have to ask a Google employee.

Comment: @stefan or maybe they are just not proud of it? :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the thing, android's latest version kitkat(4.4) is api19.

After some minor update, the current kitakt version stands at 4.4.2, however the api version remains the same at **19**.

Similarly, all the minor versions of android will not have a corresponding api verison.

Comment: Then why they explicitly mention `2.3.3` and `2.3.4` but not `2.3.5`? Was the 2.3.5 just a minor update while 2.3.4 was a major update?

Comment: The same platform version, doesnt even have reference to 4.4.2, so yeah, minor updates are not mentioned.

Comment: Probably you are right. I do think that the version numbering for android is weird though, because you cannot really see if it is a major update or not from the version number. I mean 2.3.3 is major, 2.3.5 is just minor...